# Find all differences between .mat files

Tags: matlab, file, diff, mat-file

I am looking for a way to list the differences between two .mat files, something that can be usefull for many people.

Though I searched everywhere I could think of, I have not found anything that meets my requirements:

1. Pick 2 mat files
2. Find the differences
3. Save them properly

The closest I have come is `visdiff`. As long as I stay within matlab, it will allow me to browse the differences, but when I save the result it only shows me the top level.

---

Here is a simplified example of what my files typically look like:

```
a = 6;
b.c.d = 7;
b.c.e = 'x';
save f1
f = a;
clear a
b.c.e = 'y';
save f2
visdiff('f1.mat','f2.mat')
```

If I click here on `b`, I can find the difference. However if I run this and use 'file>save', I am not able to click on `b`. Thus I still don't know what has been changed.

Note: I don't have Simulink

---

Hence my question is:

**How can I show all differences between 2 mat files to someone without Matlab**

---

Here are the answers that I personally consider to be most suitable for different situations:

- [Answer for users with Simulink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19136168/983722)
- [General answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19446308/983722)
- [Answer displaying all value differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19136535/983722)

Comment: I assume that the "File -> Save As" you mention relates to the "Save as HTML" functionality (http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_env/comparing-files-and-folders.html#brqxeeu-108). Does this not allow drilling down into structs and the like?

Comment: @am304 Have tried that, but the result is just a html 'picture' that does not allow you to click and drill down.

Comment: OK, it's probably worth reporting this as enhancement request for a future version, even if it doesn't help you right now

Comment: You can use `Simulink.saveVars`instead of `save`. see my answer

Comment: Have updated the question as I don't have Simulink available.

Comment: I don't know, but maybe `visdiff` can be used with [MATLAB Compiler](http://www.mathworks.de/products/compiler/).

Comment: @BHF That would be nice, but unfortunately it won't work. Tested it and found that [it is probably not supposed to work either](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/268454) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Simple general answer, without displaying value differences**

Due to the insight I gained from the answers of @BHF, @Daniel R and @Dennis Jaheruddin, I have managed to find a simple scalable solution:

```
[fs1, fs2, er] = comp_struct(load('f1.mat'),load('f2.mat'))
```

Note that it works for .mat containing an arbritrary number of variables.

This uses the [Compare Structures - File Exchange submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22752-compare-structures).

Comment: Can't test this now, but does it actually work? And what can be inside the save files, exactly 1 struct each or arbitrary variables?  Make sure this answer can be read on its own (without people needing to look for preparations in my existing answer for instance).

Comment: `myStruct1=load('f1.mat');` does create the variable myStruct1 with same content than yours, and nothing else. This is the effect of equal sign, and also the effect of using load's result in argument to `comp_struct`.

Comment: The best would have been to edit your answer, but a reviewer taught me on http://french.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/8954 to prefer making a standalone answer.

Comment: It works for .mat containing an arbritrary number of variables.

Comment: I just want to add that if you have a lot of (meaningless) NaNs in the structs, you may want to modify the "compare structures" code linked in htis answer so that it uses "isequaln" instead of "isequal"

Answer (score 8):

#### Find all differences between mat files without MATLAB?

You can find the differences between [HDF5](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hdf5/info) based [.mat files](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/import_export/mat-file-versions.html) with the [HDF5 Tools](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/Tools.html).

#### Example

Let me shorten your MATLAB example and assume you create two mat files with

```
clear ; a = 6 ; b.c = 'hello' ; save -v7.3 f1
clear ; a = 7 ; b.e = 'world' ; save -v7.3 f2
```

Outside MATLAB use

```
h5ls -v -r f1.mat
```

to get a listing about the kind of data included f1.mat:

```
Opened "f1.mat" with sec2 driver.
/                        Group
    Location:  1:96
    Links:     1
/a                       Dataset {1/1, 1/1}
    Attribute: MATLAB_class scalar
        Type:      6-byte null-terminated ASCII string
        Data:  "double"
    Location:  1:2576
    Links:     1
    Storage:   8 logical bytes, 8 allocated bytes, 100.00% utilization
    Type:      native double
/b                       Group
    Attribute: MATLAB_class scalar
        Type:      6-byte null-terminated ASCII string
        Data:  "struct"
    Location:  1:800
    Links:     1
/b/c                     Dataset {5/5, 1/1}
    Attribute: H5PATH scalar
        Type:      2-byte null-terminated ASCII string
        Data:  "/b"
    Attribute: MATLAB_class scalar
        Type:      4-byte null-terminated ASCII string
        Data:  "char"
    Attribute: MATLAB_int_decode scalar
        Type:      native int
        Data:  2
    Location:  1:1832
    Links:     1
    Storage:   10 logical bytes, 10 allocated bytes, 100.00% utilization
    Type:      native unsigned short
```

Use of

```
h5ls -d -r f1.mat
```

returns the values of the stored data:

```
/                        Group
/a                       Dataset {1, 1}
    Data:
        (0,0) 6
/b                       Group
/b/c                     Dataset {5, 1}
    Data:
        (0,0) 104, 101, 108, 108, 111
```

The data `104, 101, 108, 108, 111` represents the word `hello`, which can be seen with

```
h5ls -d -r f1.mat | tail -1 | awk '{FS=",";printf("%c%c%c%c%c \n",$2,$3,$4,$5,$6)}'
```

You can get the same listing for f2.mat and compare the two outputs with the tool of your choice.

Comparison also works directly with [HDF5 Tools](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/Tools.html). To compare the two numbers `a` from both files use

```
h5diff -r f1.mat f2.mat /a
```

which will show you the values and their difference

```
dataset: </a> and </a>
size:           [1x1]           [1x1]
position        a               a               difference          
------------------------------------------------------------
[ 0 0 ]          6               7               1              
1 differences found
attribute: <MATLAB_class of </a>> and <MATLAB_class of </a>>
0 differences found
```

#### Remarks

There are a few more commands and options in the [HDF5 Tools](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/Tools.html), which may help to get your real problem solved.

Binary distributions are available for Linux and Windows from [The HDF Group](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/release/obtain5.html). For OS X you can get them installed via [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/). If needed there is also a GUI: [HDFView](http://www.hdfgroup.org/hdf-java-html/hdfview/).

Comment: Curious to see whether it works for nontrivial mat files, so far I am optimistic.

Comment: If you fail in using HDF5 Tools, you may either try to contact the support teams from [Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.de/support/contact_us/) and/or [HDF group](http://www.hdfgroup.org/services/). Or try to code something on your own using any language that reads HDF5 files (e.g. python with [h5py](http://www.h5py.org/)).

Comment: I have tried `h5diffdll` and `h5lsdll`, but for nontrivial files the output is too much to be displayed in cmd. Could you give a hint on how I would get the results in a text file so I can clean them up a bit?

Comment: Looks like you are on windows, sorry I don't know how to redirect the output. For unix like systems it would be `YOUR_COMMAND > YOUR_FILE`.

Comment: Fortunately that works on windows as well, and it also reduces the processing time from half a minute to a fraction of a second!

Answer (score 5):

If you have simulink you can use [`Simulink.saveVars`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/simulink/slref/simulink.savevars.html) to generate an m-file that upon execution creates the same variables in work space:

```
a = 6;
b.c.d = 7;
b.c.e = 'x';
Simulink.saveVars('f1');
f = a;
clear a
b.c.e = 'y';
Simulink.saveVars('f2');
visdiff('f1.m','f2.m')
```

as illustrated in this sctreenshot

[image]

Note that by default it limits the number of elements in arrays to 1000 and you can increase it to 10000. Arrays larger than that limit will be saved in a separate mat-file.

**UPDATE:** From R2014a a new function similar to `Simulink.saveVars` has been added to MATLAB. see [`matlab.io.saveVariablesToScript`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/matlab.io.savevariablestoscript.html)

Comment: I have only mentioned my lack of Simulink after reading this answer. So don't downvote for only that reason.

Answer (score 4):

This is only part of the answer, but maybe it helps.

You could use [gencode](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24447-generate-m-file-code-for-any-matlab-variable), a Matlab function that generates Matlab code from a variable such that running the code reproduces the variable. You do this for all of the variables in each mat-file (takes some programming, but should be doable) and put the results in different .m-files.

Then you use a standard text comparison tool (maybe even `visdiff`) to compare the .m-files.

Comment: I have tried to implement your solution, however still encountering some difficulties. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are several good tools to compare XML-Files, this I would proceed this way:

1. Download [struct2xml.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28639-struct2xml)
2. Load both matfiles
3. Export each with struct2xml
4. compare, using XMLSpy or similar

Comment: I am yet to test it, but so far this looks like it may be the most convenient.

Comment: there are many functions on the File Exchange to convert MATLAB variables into textual representation (XML, JSON, ..). The output of those could be compared using any regular diff tool

Comment: Though this submission won't work for my structs (or even for scalars) it did point me in the right direction. After reading this answer combined with the suggestion from @Amro I realized that saving my data as plain text (and thus losing the structural nature) would make any comparison impractical. I will soon post the solution I found.

Answer (score 2):

### **Answer for small files, displaying all value differences**

Based on the suggestion by @A. Donda I have tried to use `gencode` to create a variable for everything.

Though it works for my toy example, it is quite slow and tells me that I exceed the allowed amount of variables for my real .mat files.

Anyway, for those who are looking for something that works with small files, I will post this option:

```
wList=who;
for iLoop = 1:numel(wList)
    eval(['generated_' wList{iLoop} '= gencode(' wList{iLoop} ');'])
    for jLoop = 1:numel(eval(['generated_' wList{iLoop}]))
        eval(['generated_' wList{iLoop} '_' num2str(jLoop) '= generated_' wList{iLoop} '(' num2str(jLoop) ');' ])
    end
end
```

Though it may work, I don't feel like this is the best way to go.

Comment: Yes, I guess this way only makes sense when the generated m-files have a reasonable size. The only thing I can think of is to modify gencode, so that if there are large data matrices involved in the data structure, to not generate code to recreate them but to make a kind of summary of their contents, e.g. using a [checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum).

Answer (score 1):

### **General answer, without displaying value differences**

Due to the insight I gained from the answers of @BHF and @Daniel R I have managed to find a reasonably scalable solution.

**Step 1: Save all variables from each files as a single struct**

This uses the [Save workspace to struct - File Exchange submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36257-save-workspace-to-struct).

Here are the steps to take assuming you want to compare `f1.mat` and `f2.mat`:

```
clear
load f1
myStruct1 = ws2struct;
save myStruct1 myStruct1 
clear
load f2
myStruct2 = ws2struct;
save myStruct2 myStruct2 
clear                    
load myStruct1
load myStruct2
```

**Step 2: Compare the structs**

This uses the [Compare Structures - File Exchange submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22752-compare-structures)

Given that you want to compare `myStruct1` and `myStruct2` you can simply call:

```
[fs1, fs2, er] = comp_struct(myStruct1,myStruct2)
```

---

I was positively surprised at how readable the list of differences in `er` is, here is the output for the example that was used in the question:

er =

```
's2 is missing field a'
's1(1).b(1).c(1).e and s2(1).b(1).c(1).e do not match'
```

Note that it will not show values, from a technical point of view it is probably not too hard to change the m file if value difference displays are desirable. However, especially if there are some big matrices I suppose this could result in problematic output.

Comment: The accepted answer simplifies this. I will leave this answer here as I am not sure whether the accepted answer is valid for older versions of Matlab.